# Removing object temporarily from object storage - TYPO3

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have 2 models banners and files. Banners and files were connected via mm relation. The banner object containing the files as object storage. When I remove a file from object storage the file being deleted. How can I only remove the relation instead of removing object?

```
$banner->getFiles();
```

return an object storage.

```
 $files = $banner->getFiles();
   foreach($files as $file){
       $uid = $file->getUid();
       if($uid==4){
           $banner->removeFiles($file);
       }
   }
```

When I done the above code the field deleted of file model updated to 1

Comment: Your question is quite vague. Are you actually calling the delete() method on the File object? Then, instead, just use the remove method on the Banner object. That should remove the relation and keep the File object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In what kind of action you want this process? The file should only be really deleted if you persist the $banner object with an action redirect or manually with the PersistenceManager.

Maybe you can also clone the ObjectStorage and then detach some objects.

```
$files = clone $banner->getFiles();
   foreach($files as $file){
       $uid = $file->getUid();
       if($uid==4){
           $files->detach($file);
       }
   }
```

In this solution all files should remain in $banner but UID4 is removed inside $files variable.

**UPDATE:** See comments below. The deleted=1 was caused by @cascade remove annotation inside the model.

Comment: If $files inside your $banner model declared as @cascade remove?

Comment: its declared as @cascade remove

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps but try to remove the annotation, clear the caches in install tool and try again to remove some items of the ObjectStorage.